# Is possible add class for last post of Custom Post Type?

Tags: custom-post-types, css

I need to add a different class for last post of a Custom Post Type. Is it possible?

I have found this code, but it works only in posts

```
function wpc_last_post_class( $classes ) {
    global $wp_query;  
    if(($wp_query->current_post+1) == $wp_query->post_count) $classes[] = 'last'; // change the class name  you would like to add here  
    return $classes;  
}  
add_filter('post_class', 'wpc_last_post_class');
```

Comment: Do you use the [`post_class()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) function in the template file responsible for displaying the custom post type?

Comment: You could try the accepted method here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610985/add-extra-class-to-last-item-in-wp-loop

Comment: There's no reason this wouldn't work on a custom post type, unless you're not using `post_class()` in your template, or you're not using the main query.

Answer (score 1):

Not *exactly* what you asked for, but given that classes are *primarily* used for styling, might you consider using CSS pseudo-class ":last-child" instead of PHP code?

Here's some information on how to style using :last-child

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-child/